# layout CSS working perfectly in safari but not in firefox?

Tags: php, html, css

I have used Safari to view my layout up until now.  Everything appeared perfectly as I wanted it to in Safari, a simple layout with a logo, navigation bar, header image, and then a two column body area.  However, in Firefox, both the header image and logo are not even displaying, and the two column float for the body area is not working and instead sinking into one... I am not sure what is going on, or what types of problems I will encounter in other browsers, but maybe someone can find what is wrong:

```
body {
background-color: some color;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 950px;
 background-color: some color;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 border-right: 1px solid some color;
 border-left: 1px solid some color;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url('some url');
 height: 100 px;
 text-align: left;
 border-style: none;
}

#navigation {
 background-color: some color;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 2px solid some color;
 border-bottom: 2px solid some color;
 height: 30 px;
}

#navigationElement { 
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 2 px;
 padding-left: 10 px;
 padding-right: 10 px;
 border-style: none;
}

#navigationElement a:link { 
 color: some color;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navigationElement a:hover { 
 color: some color;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#headerImg {
 background-image: url('some url');
 height: 200 px;
 text-align: left;
 border-style: none;
}

#left {
 background-color: some color;
 width: 475 px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: none;
}

#leftElement {
 background-color: some color;
 padding: 40 px;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: none;
}

#right {
 background-color: some color;
 width: 475 px;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: none;
}

#rightElement {
 background-color: some color;
 padding: 40 px;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: none;
}

#footer {
 background-color: some color;
 height: 40 px;
 text-align: left;
 border-style: none;
 clear: both;
}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="logo"></div>

<div id="navigation">

<div id="navigationElement"><a href="link1">nav 1</a></div>
<div id="navigationElement"><a href="link2">nav 2</a></div>
<div id="navigationElement"><a href="link3">nav 3</a></div>


</div>

<div id="headerImg"></div>

<div id="bodyArea">

    <div id="left">

        <div id="leftElement">
        left element text 1 
        </div>

        <div id="leftElement">
        left element text 2
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <div id="rightElement">
        right element text 1 
        </div>

        <div id="rightElement"> 
        right element text 2
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">some footer text</div>

</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Can I see the HTML? Or the actual CSS that doesn't have `some this` or `some that`?

Comment: Seeing the html code would help too

Comment: @Jen Please create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: background-color: some color; what does this suppose to be??

Comment: I added the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are using spaces between values and px in height attributes (i.e `height: 100 px;` should be `height: 100px;`). Different browsers handle these kind of errors differently, so it's always a good idea to validate your css when you're having weird errors: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between your pixel values.

`height: 100 px;` to `height: 100px;`